# how to sum rows of mysql ouput in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like

```
id  user_id     white   brown   green   other   day     month   year    week

6   54          5       5       2       0       30      11      2015    49
5   48          1       3       1       0       1       12      2015    49

4   2           2       1       2       0       1       12      2015    49
```

What I am trying to do is select all the records where day == $day
but I would like the values of the colors to be added together so that instead of showing two records where day = 1.
Show one result where

```
white = 3 
brown = 4 
green = 3 
and other = 0
```

I have been playing around with my php script for a few hours but I just cant seem to get anything to work for me.

The code snippet that is working

```
$sql = mysql_query(  "SELECT sum(white) AS white, sum(brown) AS brown, sum(green) AS green, sum(other) AS other FROM eggs WHERE day = '1'");


  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

  ?><tr></td>
<td align="center"><?PHP echo $row['white']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?PHP echo $row['brown']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?PHP echo $row['green']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?PHP echo $row['other']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?PHP echo $total_eggs_today; ?></td>
</tr>
    <?PHP 
   }
```

By modifying some examples posted here by waitfor I have a working script. The answer was actually fairly simple but for some reason I that I had to retrieve results and then work with.
It was definitely a face palm moment.

Comment: Please show what you have in your script so far, and which part isn't working as expected.

Comment: does it needs to be in `php` script? `mysql` can do that for you using the `sum()` function

Comment: Where's the PHP code here?

Comment: Doing it in MySql will be much easier and better: `Select sum(white), sum(brown), sum(green), sum(other) from table where day=@day`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think.. this example helps to you

```
<?php
  $sql = 
  "select 
      sum(white) white, sum(brown) brown, sum(green) green, sum(other) other 
  from 
      table 
  where 
      day = 1";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
      print_r($row);
  }
?>
```